# Checker Framework argument.type.incompatible undesired positive

Tags: java, checker-framework

So I'm getting this error from the nullness checker

```
> Task :compileJava
/Users/calebcushing/IdeaProjects/ppm/scaf/src/main/java/com/xenoterracide/scaf/PebbleTemplateProcessor.java:94: error: [argument.type.incompatible] incompatible argument for parameter obj of requireNonNull.
        var console = Objects.requireNonNull( System.console() );
                                                            ^                                     ^
```

this is complaining that `System.console()` could be null, which upon reading the javadoc is true. So I wrapped it in `Objects.requireNonNull()` now it's complaining that the argument to `requireNonNull` can't be null, which is obviously not true.

How do I tell `NullnessChecker` to ignore `Objects.requireNonNull()`? I'm fine with NPE's that are explicit, it's just the accidental ones I don't want. I believe checker already ships with a stub for this.

Answer (score 1):

Realize I'm late to the game, but hopefully this will help others who land here after searching.

You can provide a [stub file](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#stub) to Checker which overrides the default annotations.

For my own project, I created a new folder called `checker` alongside the `src` folder in one of my common projects, and dropped in a stub file `java.util.Objects.astub` with these contents:

```java
package java.util;

import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.Nullable;

public class Objects
{
   public static <T> T requireNonNull(@Nullable T obj, String message);
}
```

Then I added this to our Gradle build:

```
checkerFramework {
   extraJavacArgs = [
      "-Astubs=${project(':my-project').file('checker')}"
   ]
}
```

…where `my-project` is the Gradle identifier for the project containing the new folder.

Checker will now load all `*.astub` files in that `checker` folder, and use the annotations provided there instead of the defaults. You can learn more at [Using Stub Classes](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#stub) in the Checker documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The below answers were written for the original post, which had 3 unrelated questions in it.  (The poster later edited the original post.)  I have no clue why this answer was downvoted, since it accurately answers all 3 questions, and gives links for additional information.

Please ask [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).

> The first one was complaining that `System.console()` could be null, which upon reading the javadoc is true. So I wrapped it in `Objects.requireNonNull()` now it's complaining that the argument to `requireNonNull` can't be null, which is obviously not true.

This is answered in the [introduction to the Checker Framework manual](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#annotate-normal-behavior).

The goal of the Nullness Checker is to warn you if your program might throw a `NullPointerException`.
If the argument to `requireNonNull()` is `null`, then your program throws a `NullPointerException`.
Therefore, passing `null` to `requireNonNull()` leaves your program no more correct than passing `null` to any other routine that might dereference it, and the Nullness Checker warns about it.

You tried to silence the warning by writing `requireNonNull()`.
As noted above, this has no effect:  the program still throws `NullPointerException`.
Instead, it is better to correct the underlying problem.  Your program should check for null and issue a user-friendly message rather than crashing -- whether the crash is in your own code or in `requireNonNull()`.

> The second one is complaining about commons-lang3 parameter not being able to take null, but its documentation says otherwise.

This is also answered in the [introduction to the Checker Framework manual](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#handling-warnings).

The Nullness Checker reads annotations, not English Javadoc comments.
In order for the Nullness Checker to know that `toBoolean()` can take a null argument, its signature of `toBoolean()` needs to be annotated as:

```java
boolean toBoolean(@Nullable Boolean bool)
```

As explained in [the manual](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#annotating-libraries), you can write that annotation so that the Nullness Checker will use it.
You can also contribute commons-lang annotations back to the community, so that others can also benefit from them.

> I added SuppressWarnings, not certain why it's still happening.

You need to write `@SuppressWarnings` where the warning is being issued, which is on the declaration of the `Application` class.  You wrote `@SuppressWarnings` on a different line of your program.

Comment: Re: commons-lang3 I know it doesn't read comments.. I Was tired when writing this. Outside of upstream patches how do I fix this?

Comment: Please see the [chapter of the manual](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#annotating-libraries) that I linked to in my answer.  You probably want to create a stub file, which is described there.

Comment: > the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline [How To Answer (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("initialization.fields.uninitialize")` I tried putting this on the constructor and on the class, I'm still getting this error.

`/Users/calebcushing/IdeaProjects/ppm/scaf/src/main/java/com/xenoterracide/scaf/Application.java:24: error: [initialization.fields.uninitialized] the constructor does not initialize fields: arg, args, dir
  Application() {
  ^`

Comment: split that one off, if you want to partially move your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/q/65245465/206466

Comment: and here https://stackoverflow.com/q/65245508/206466