# Checker Framework initialization.fields.uninitialize false positive

Tags: java, checker-framework

Here's my error

```
  found   : @Initialized @Nullable String
  required: @Initialized @NonNull String
/Users/calebcushing/IdeaProjects/ppm/scaf/src/main/java/com/xenoterracide/scaf/Application.java:21: error: [initialization.fields.uninitialized] the constructor does not initialize fields: arg, args, dir
public final class Application implements Runnable {
             ^
3 errors
```

These are initialized by picocli, so I added SuppressWarnings, not certain why it's still happening.

```java
  @SuppressWarnings({ "NullAway.Init", "initialization.fields.uninitialize" })
  @CommandLine.Parameters( index = "0", description = "first configuration directory" )
  private String arg;

  @SuppressWarnings({ "NullAway.Init", "initialization.fields.uninitialize" })
  @CommandLine.Parameters(
    index = "1..*",
    description = "path to configuration directories separated by space"
  )
  private List<String> args;

  @SuppressWarnings({ "NullAway.Init", "initialization.fields.uninitialize" })
  @CommandLine.Option(
    names = {"-d", "--dir"},
    defaultValue = ".config/scaf",
    showDefaultValue = CommandLine.Help.Visibility.ALWAYS,
    description = "Directory path from the current working directory. " +
      "Templates and configs are looked up relative to here"
  )
  private Path dir;
```

I've tried putting

```
  @SuppressWarnings({ "NullAway.Init", "initialization.fields.uninitialize"})
```

on the class, the constructor and as you can see, the field. How do I make checkerframework happy?

[here is the full source code](https://github.com/xenoterracide/brix/blob/master/src/main/java/com/xenoterracide/brix/Application.java) checker framework is not currently enabled in it due to the fact this wouldn't compile if I did.

Comment: You said you put `@SuppressWarnings` on the class, but that is not in the code you showed.  Could you please provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @mernst you mean you've tried what I put inside of a class and you didn't have this problem?

Comment: No.  It's easier, less error-prone, and more in line with SO guidelines, for you to show what you did than for me to fumble around guessing at what you might have done.

Comment: updated to include a link to the full source.

Comment: @mernst updated to include checkerframework branch https://github.com/xenoterracide/brix/tree/checkerframework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checker framework is complaining because in your `main` method you are not initializing the instance fields `arg`, `args` and `dir`. If you not annotate a field explicitly, for the checker framework point of view, the field is considered to be `@NotNull`.

Please, try to annotate that fields with `@Nullable`:

```java
  @CommandLine.Parameters( index = "0", description = "first configuration directory" )
  private @Nullable String arg;

  @CommandLine.Parameters(
    index = "1..*",
    description = "path to configuration directories separated by space"
  )
  private @Nullable List<String> args;

  @CommandLine.Option(
    names = {"-d", "--dir"},
    defaultValue = ".config/scaf",
    showDefaultValue = CommandLine.Help.Visibility.ALWAYS,
    description = "Directory path from the current working directory. " +
      "Templates and configs are looked up relative to here"
  )
  private @Nullable Path dir;
```

Although you configured `picocli` to provide default values, checker framework only knows that after the `main` method invocation these fields are not initialized, there is no such initialization code, `picocli` will provide the default value you indicated but checker framework is not aware of that, that is why it is complaining about it.

Having said that, if you prefer to suppress warnings, please, be aware that checker framework is indicating the warning type that must be suppressed, `initialization.fields.uninitialized`, and it seems you have a typo in the code:

```java
@SuppressWarnings({ "NullAway.Init", "initialization.fields.uninitialize" })
```

Please, note the difference between the required value, `initialization.fields.uninitialized`, and the one you provided, `initialization.fields.uninitialize`.

Comment: ah yes, I forgot when I posted my source, that I have since migrated my annotations to jetbrains, they were previously using checker ones when I first opened this. 

Hmm... but given that issue is not the real issue, these are framework instantiated, and the framework ensure that they are not null by how I've configured it, so they shouldn't be marked `@Nullable` I'm trying to suppress the errors because I know better, though I understand why checker does not.

Comment: updated in branch checkerframework https://github.com/xenoterracide/brix/tree/checkerframework

Comment: Hi @xenoterracide. Sorry for the late reply. There are a lot of changes!! As far I understand, you updated the code to allow for the correct use of the checker framework, is it right? Does the problem persist? The problem is that although you include the checker framework and include de `SuppressWarnings```, some fields are still being reported as with error, am I correct? I will try to configure your project, I was unable to use a JVM 11 in this laptop, this is why I could not expand my answer in your previous question.

Comment: @jccamparno yes. huh, about jvm 11.

Comment: Please @xenoterracide, read my comment again. I am aware that this have nothing to do with Java 11, but your code is written from Java 11 onwards. I just try to explain that in order to help you I installed a JVM 11 in this laptop. Having said that, to answer your question initially I gave you some advice regarding the use of the right annotations: although NullAway will recognize annotations by its literal name, I think if you are using checker framework it is better to use the proper annotations instead of the ones provide by a library of Jetbrains. See next comment

Comment: I tried to explain also what the problem actually is and how you can solve it by including the necessary `@Nullable` annotations. You indicated that you prefer or do not want to include those annotations because you already know that these values will never be `null`. I indicated you in a comment that it is right, but checker framework does not have that knowledge. You changed the annotations for the right ones in a new git branch. In my last comment I am just trying to understand what the problem actually is.  See next comment

Comment: If the actual problem is that the `SuppressWarnings` annotations are not working properly, please, see my updated answer: I think there is a typo in your code, and you are trying to suppress warnings for `initialization.fields.uninitialize` when you should use instead `initialization.fields.uninitialized`. I hope it helps.

Comment: gah, all that for a typo... the jetbrains annotations part of this answer is completely irrelevant, as it was not part of the original question, and only came up because I forgot to put the checker ones back before linking the code, and to be honest turns out that wasn't relevant either.

Comment: Yes @xenoterracide, I agree with you, probably if you change the typo in the `SupressWarnings` annotation the problem will be solved. Please, can you try? I will remove the part of my answer related with the use of a different set of annotations if you consider it necessary. Sorry, I did not realized the typo until today because I was focused in give you an answer based on the use of the checker framework annotations.

Comment: That is great @xenoterracide. I am happy to see that it worked properly. As I told you in my previous comment, sorry, I didn't realized the typo until this morning.

Comment: @xenoterracide I updated the answer to remove the part related with the different types of annotations. In any case, if you updated your code to use the checker framework annotations, please, do not change it again, I think they are more suitable for null checking and for your specific configuration than the jetbrains ones