# Checker Framework argument.type.incompatible false positive with commons-lang3

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, checker-framework

Here's my error (and yes there is an open bug on commons-lang3 jira).

```
  found   : @Initialized @Nullable Console
  required: @Initialized @NonNull Console
/Users/calebcushing/IdeaProjects/ppm/scaf/src/main/java/com/xenoterracide/scaf/PebbleTemplateProcessor.java:96: error: [argument.type.incompatible] incompatible argument for parameter str of toBoolean.
        if ( BooleanUtils.toBoolean( line ) ) {
```

I tried making this `src/java/main/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.astub` and I tried putting that file in `src/main/resources/`

```java
package org.apache.commons.lang3;

import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;


public class BooleanUtils {

  @NonNull
  public static boolean toBoolean( @Nullable final String str);
}
```

but I and adding this to my gradle config

```
  extraJavacArgs.addAll(listOf(
    "-Werror",
    "-Astubs=BooleanUtils.astub:stubs"
  ))
```

but I get

```
warning: Did not find stub file BooleanUtils.astub on classpath or within current directory
warning: Did not find stub file stubs on classpath or within current directory
```

how do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, no thanks to https://checkerframework.org/manual/#stub, the gradle plugin actually has a useful example of just this https://github.com/kelloggm/checkerframework-gradle-plugin#providing-checker-specific-options-to-the-compiler

you need to provide a path from the project itself, this is what I did.

```
  extraJavacArgs.addAll(listOf(
    "-Werror",
    "-Astubs=${rootDir}/config/checker/stubs/BooleanUtils.astub"
  ))
```

I used `${rootDir}` because `./config...` was looking in `.gradle`